# PHP server that can be run without an installer (from USB)

Tags: website, php, web-server

I hope this is not a stupid question but I do not know PHP but need to run a PHP application from a USB stick.

This is not a complex application (is a demo presentation). It has not database backend for example, just PHP, HTML, JS and CSS files.

I want something very simple: web server + PHP libs. That is it. I so far looked at Server2Go, XAMPP, WAMP, Apache2+PHP but I can't believe there is not a "lite" version for a PHP server (or maybe I am not looking for the right things).

Is there some simple web server, no install, that will allow me to run simple PHP app from an USb stick?

Thank you all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP server that can be run without an installer (from USB)](http://serverfault.com/questions/213840/php-server-that-can-be-run-without-an-installer-from-usb)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you're looking for: http://www.uniformserver.com/